# What is the correct way of calling a instantiated class function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, oop

There are two classes, **class LoginRoute** and **class LoginController**. Class LoginRoute, a private variable of LoginController type which gets initialised as expected. However, when an object function is called, there is some erratic behaviour.

**Case A**
If the LoginController object function is called directly from the router, then the object seems to get destroyed (cannot reference to *this*).

**Case B**
If the LoginController object function is called within a callback function from the router, then the object sis preserved (can reference to *this*)

```
class LoginRoute {
    private _loginController: LoginController

    constructor () {
        this._loginController = new LoginController()  
    }
    get routes () : express.Router {
        let router = express.Router()

    // ******************* CASE A (Not working)*****************
        router.post('/loginA', this._loginController.login) 


    // ******************* CASE B (Working)*****************
        router.post('/loginB', (req : express.Request, res :  express.Response) => {  
            this._loginController.login(req, res)
        })
        return router
    }
}
```

The controller class is as below

```
class LoginController {
    login(req: express.Request, res: express.Response):void {
        console.log(req.body)
        this.sample()
    }
    sample () {
        console.log('Sample')
    }
}
```

In both cases **/loginA and /loginB**, I would expect to see the same output. However, **"this" in to be undefined in A, while working perfectly in B.** The express parameters of req and res and passing perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because context of "this" at **/loginA** is referring the window obj, as while at **/loginB** "this" is with in a arrow function, it obviously refers to class obj.

check this video for more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA